# How could I know whether org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.setText(html) renderred html completed

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

org.eclipse.swt.events.Progresslistner{
      public void completed(ProgressEvent e){}
  }

the method completed(ProgressEvent) only means the browser has loaded the html, but still not ready to render. 
  What I needed is a callback when render completed. Is there any way could do this?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need method `changed()` from [`LocationListener`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rap.help/help/html/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/browser/LocationListener.html) and test whether `event.top` is `true`